# Нет доступа к расоположению файла после его загрузки через php

Tags: windows, apache, php, windows-8, apache2

Здравствуйте. Не могу открыть изображение после того как загружаю его через php. Делаю сайт на локальной машине в 8-й винде. Когда в нужную папку (localhost/site/img) просто помещаю изображение, то оно открывается без проблем. После того как загружаю в эту же папку изображение через php, то открыть это изображение уже не получается и винда выдает след. сообщение: "Средство просмотра фотографий не может открыть это изображение, так как отсутствует разрешение на доступ к расположению файла". Браузер также не может открыть это изображение. При этом админом и владельцем папки являюсь я, права стоят на все действия (полный доступ). В чем проблема и как её решить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

А Апач имеет права на чтение из данной папки? Мне кажется нет, поэтому и ничего не выводит браузер. Разберитесь с правами на папки Вашего проекта.

Comment: в php скрипте прописал относительные пути, теперь браузер открывает, но по прежнему не могу открыть эти изображения руками. С правами разбирался, но пока только получается выставить права отдельному файлу после загрузки. После того как новый файл загружается на сервер, права слетают, и ему снова нужно выставлять права и владельца. Ума не приложу че за дурдом...

Comment: Так под каким пользователем работает Апач (какой User в httpd.conf)?   Даны ли этому пользователю права на запись в интересующую нас папку localhost/site/img - и только в нее! Для этого отмените наследование прав от вышестоящих папок и перепишите все по-новой.  У Апача на остальные папки проекта должно быть только право на чтение и исполнение (т.к. php).

Answer (score 0):

А вы случайно не перебезопасились? Если включен UAC, то на открытие любых файлов, закаченных из и-нета, выдаётся запрос. И если вы однажды решили не открывать этот файл, и случайно включили галочку "Больше не спрашивать", то так оно и будет!